# In Visual Studio I keep getting two copies of FormMain.cs and one contains old edits, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008 I keep getting two copies of my FormMain.cs file, one contains old edits, I've rebuilt the project and the solution but this doesn't fix it, what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the file attributes (right-click and select Properties in windows explorer)

Make sure you're not having the Read-only flag set.

[alt text http://chakrit.net/files/stackoverflow/readonly.png](http://chakrit.net/files/stackoverflow/readonly.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may also check the localization property. Maybe you added an unwanted localized clone of this form.